# How do I use createPattern with a spritesheet?

Tags: html5, html-canvas, spritesheet

Say that I have a spritesheet like this

[image: simple spritesheet]

And I want to use the dirt tile at (1, 1). I know that I can repeat an entire image using `createPattern` but how do I create the pattern from just the tile section of the image? So far I have this

```
var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
```

I know I could use repeated calls to `ctx.drawImage` but is it possible to get the same effect using patterns?

Comment: Please see this question on the main StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084169/using-a-sprite-sheet-with-createpattern

Comment: Oh snap, I'm not sure how I missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I found out by following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084169/using-a-sprite-sheet-with-createpattern).

`context.drawImage` can take an [*img*, *canvas*, or *video* element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage%28%29). So you can decide to use the contents of an off-screen canvas as a pattern.

```
// First we create a canvas to draw our pattern on
// Doesn't actually have to be in the DOM
var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
offscreenCanvas.width = textureWidth;
offscreenCanvas.height = textureHeight;

// Grab it's context and render to it
var offscreenContext = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');
offscreenContext.drawImage(
    texture,       // the Image
    sourceX,       // X offset on the spritesheet
    sourceY,       // Y offset on the spritesheet
    textureWidth,  // Width of the sprite
    textureHeight, // Height of the sprite
    0,             // Destination X
    0,             // Destination Y
    textureWidth,  // Destination width
    textureHeight  // Destination height
);
```

Now here's the fun part: creating a pattern from our "invisible" canvas.

```
// Can use 'repeat', 'repeat-x', 'repeat-y', or 'no-repeat'
var pattern = context.createPattern(offscreenCanvas, 'repeat');
context.fillStyle = pattern;
context.fillRect(x, y, textureWidth, textureHeight);
```

As an added bonus, this is [much faster than making multiple `drawImage` calls](http://jsperf.com/multiple-drawimage-vs-pattern).

Comment: WARNING: **The JSPerf linked above causes repeated crashing of my graphics driver for the drawPattern**!

Comment: I shrank down the test area so hopefully it won't crash any more drivers haha.